# One sided attractors in a one dimensional continuous time system

Tags: dynamical-systems

I am trying to find a (relatively) simple closed formula for a continuous dynamic system where a local asymptotic equilibrium $x^*$ is bracketed by two 'one-sided' attractors $x_l$ and $x_h$. So I want to find a continuous $f()$ for a system
$$
\dot{x} = f(x)
$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}$, such that from states $x < x_l$ we converge to $x_l$, from $x > x_h$ we converge to $x_h$, and for $x_l < x < x_h$ we converge to $x^*$.

Answer (score 1):

I think
$$
f(x) = -\left(x-1\right)^{2}x\left(x+1\right)^{2}
$$
works, perhaps there are simpler examples.

[image]